# rx_queue value in /proc/net/udp grows to twice the SO_RCVBUF value

Tags: networking, linux-networking, udp

When using an `SO_RCVBUF` of 10485760 (which is also the current limit as stipulated by `sysctl`'s `net.core.rmem_max` setting, and sending UDP packets faster than the receiving side is able to handle, the `rx_queue` column in `/proc/net/udp` always grows to pretty much exactly twice the size of `SO_RCVBUF`. 20972544 was the highest value I could observe.

So **is the SO_RCVBUF not being adhered to**? Or is the output of /proc/net/udp wrong?

My system:

```
uname -a
Linux mybox 4.3.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.3.3-5 (2016-01-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) man page:

> ```
>    SO_RCVBUF
>           Sets or gets the maximum socket receive buffer in bytes.  The
>           kernel doubles this value (to allow space for bookkeeping
>           overhead) when it is set using setsockopt(2), and this doubled
>           value is returned by getsockopt(2).  The default value is set
>           by the /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default file, and the maximum
>           allowed value is set by the /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max file.
>           The minimum (doubled) value for this option is 256.
> ```

Note that the man page indicates the kernel will double the specified buffer value for bookkeeping overhead.